# Error: passing x as 'this' argument of x discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, class, c++11, operator-overloading, stdset

I'm writing a `HeartbeatManager` for my application (in visual studio). The data of 1 heartbeat is stored in a `Heart` object. The `Heart` objects are stored in an `std::set`. For this reason, I am implementing the `operator=`, `operator<` and `operator>` overloads.

When defining these functions you can only use `const` members. I tried to do this but still get an error saying I'm not:

```
passing const HeartbeatManager::Heart' as 'this' argument of 'bool HeartbeatManager::Heart::operator<(const HeartbeatManager::Heart&)' 
discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

Here is the code. I don't see where I'm using a non-constant:

```
class HeartbeatManager
{
public:
    class Heart
    {
    public:
        Heart(const IPAddress _ip, const uint16_t _port, int _lifetime = 5000)
            : ip(_ip), port(_port), lifetime(_lifetime) {}

        const IPAddress ip;
        const uint16_t port;
        int lifetime;
        /**
        * Ages the Heart, returns whether it survived (lifetime after aging > 0)
        */
        bool age(int ms) 
        {
            this->lifetime -= ms;
            return 0 < this->lifetime;
        }

        // overloaded operators so heart struct can be sorted and used in map
        bool operator=(const Heart& o) {
            return ip == o.ip && port == o.port;
        }

        bool operator<(const Heart& o) {
            return (uint32_t)ip < (uint32_t)o.ip || (ip == o.ip && port < o.port);
        }

        bool operator>(const Heart& o) {
            return (uint32_t)ip > (uint32_t)o.ip || (ip == o.ip && port > o.port);
        }
    };
    void heartbeat(IPAddress ip, uint16_t port, int sec = 5000);
};
```

I'm very new to C++. So if this is a bad practice for making an object fit the set requirements feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to allow your compare operators to be called on a `const` object, so replace

```
bool operator < (const Heart &o) {
```

with

```
bool operator < (const Heart &o) const {
```

and so on.

Also note that you have implemented `operator = ()` rather than `operator == ()`

Answer (score 2):

> The Heart objects are stored in an std::set. For this reason I am implementing the =, < and > operators.

It's fine to define as many operators as you like (more operators do give your class more flexibility). However, the use of `std::set` justifies only `operator<`; a default set does not make use of "greater than" or "equal to" (which presumably is what you thought a single equal sign would mean).

> When defining these functions you can only use const members. I tried to do this but still get an error saying I'm not:

Take a moment to think about what you are doing. You want to be able to compare two objects using syntax like `A < B`. As you stated, these should be considered constants by `operator<`. Emphasis on *"these"*. There are *two* objects. There should be *two* `const` qualifications. Let's take a look at the operator declaration mentioned in the error message:

> `bool HeartbeatManager::Heart::operator<(const HeartbeatManager::Heart&)`

How many times does "`const`" appear in that declaration? Only once! You need another "`const`". Where should it go? The error message comes to the rescue again: it complains about the `this` argument. Whether or not `*this` is considered to be constant is determined by [the presence or absence of the `const` keyword after the parameter list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-.2C_volatile-.2C_and_ref-qualified_member_functions):

```
bool HeartbeatManager::Heart::operator<(const HeartbeatManager::Heart&) const
```

Comment: _"std::set justifies only operator<"_ Not true - you can specify which comparator the `set` should use, so if you want maximum flexibility for your class you implement more than one.

Comment: @SidS If you specify a comparator, then you could get away with no defined operators. Hence a set *justifies* `operator<` rather than *requires* it. Maximum flexibility does justify defining more operators (i.e. it's fine to define them), but the question does not use flexibility as a justification for the existence of operators; it uses storage in a set to justify them.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking a *const-qualified lvalue reference* to the `Heart`. The means the function is not mutating the instance passed. Hence they all should be [`const` qualified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison).

```
bool operator==(const Heart& o) const
//          ^^^--> typo         ^^^^^
{
    return ip == o.ip && port == o.port;
}
bool operator<(const Heart& o) const
//                             ^^^^^
{
    return (uint32_t)ip < (uint32_t)o.ip || (ip == o.ip && port < o.port);
}
bool operator>(const Heart& o)  const
//                              ^^^^^
{
    return (uint32_t)ip > (uint32_t)o.ip || (ip == o.ip && port > o.port);
}
```

---

That being said, your `operator<` and `operator>` could be simplified using lexicographical comparison provided by [std::tie](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp)

```
bool operator< (const Heart& o) const
{
    return std::tie(ip, port) < std::tie(o.ip, o.port);
}
bool operator> (const Heart& o)  const
{
    return std::tie(o.ip, o.port) < std::tie(ip, port);
}
```

Comment: `return !(*this < o);` returns `true` when the objects are equal.  Not suitable for `operator > ()`.

Comment: `operator > ()` could simply `return o < *this;`